Handling copyPast clipboard popup in Jetpack compose
I'm using Jetpack compose to create UI in my android app. I have this little problem : The android's cut/Copy/Paste popup looks misplaced when we scroll on the Lazy column. The popup sticks there but the other elements scrolls up and down. I want it to behave like we have in Gmail app or dismissed when user scroll.
here I have added a todo in my code where I can handle this popup
@Composable
private fun ResultUI(modifier: Modifier,
                     results: List<DictionaryResult>,
                     onDefinitionTap: (String) -> Unit,
                     onExampleTap: (String) -> Unit) {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState(
        // TODO detect scroll change and dismiss or move cutCopyPaste popup
    )
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier.padding(top = 8.dp), state = lazyListState){
        item {
            TextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange =  {})
        }
        items(results) {
            for(m in it.meanings ?: emptyList()) {
                MeaningUi(meaning = m, onDefinitionTap, onExampleTap)
            }
        }
    }
}

I need to know how to handle this Android's cutCopyPaste popup programmatically.
To explain my question in simple way I have added two Gifs
What I want
What I have

You can accomplish this with a custom TextToolbar. AndroidTextToolbar is the default one. You can copy it and modify based on your requirements.
I copy-pasted default one, since changing it might take some time. You can modify it based on your requirements. Second one uses  copy-paste which can be modified.
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        val view = LocalView.current

        val textToolbar = remember {
            AndroidTextToolbar(view)
        }

        var text1 by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }

        var text2 by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }

        TextField(value = text1, onValueChange = { text1 = it })

        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalTextToolbar provides textToolbar
        ) {
            TextField(value = text2, onValueChange = { text2 = it })
        }
    }
}

internal class AndroidTextToolbar(private val view: View) : TextToolbar {
    private var actionMode: ActionMode? = null
    private val textActionModeCallback: TextActionModeCallback = TextActionModeCallback(
        onActionModeDestroy = {
            actionMode = null
        }
    )
    override var status: TextToolbarStatus = TextToolbarStatus.Hidden
        private set

    override fun showMenu(
        rect: Rect,
        onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)?,
        onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)?
    ) {
        textActionModeCallback.rect = rect
        textActionModeCallback.onCopyRequested = onCopyRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onCutRequested = onCutRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onPasteRequested = onPasteRequested
        textActionModeCallback.onSelectAllRequested = onSelectAllRequested
        if (actionMode == null) {
            status = TextToolbarStatus.Shown
            actionMode = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                TextToolbarHelperMethods.startActionMode(
                    view,
                    FloatingTextActionModeCallback(textActionModeCallback),
                    ActionMode.TYPE_FLOATING
                )
            } else {
                view.startActionMode(
                    PrimaryTextActionModeCallback(textActionModeCallback)
                )
            }
        } else {
            actionMode?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun hide() {
        status = TextToolbarStatus.Hidden
        actionMode?.finish()
        actionMode = null
    }
}

/**
 * This class is here to ensure that the classes that use this API will get verified and can be
 * AOT compiled. It is expected that this class will soft-fail verification, but the classes
 * which use this method will pass.
 */
@RequiresApi(23)
internal object TextToolbarHelperMethods {
    @RequiresApi(23)
    @DoNotInline
    fun startActionMode(
        view: View,
        actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback,
        type: Int
    ): ActionMode? {
        return view.startActionMode(
            actionModeCallback,
            type
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(23)
    @DoNotInline
    fun invalidateContentRect(actionMode: ActionMode) {
        actionMode.invalidateContentRect()
    }
}


internal class TextActionModeCallback(
    val onActionModeDestroy: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var rect: Rect = Rect.Zero,
    var onCopyRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onPasteRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onCutRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    var onSelectAllRequested: (() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        requireNotNull(menu) { "onCreateActionMode requires a non-null menu" }
        requireNotNull(mode) { "onCreateActionMode requires a non-null mode" }

        onCopyRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Copy)
        }
        onPasteRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Paste)
        }
        onCutRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Cut)
        }
        onSelectAllRequested?.let {
            addMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.SelectAll)
        }
        return true
    }

    // this method is called to populate new menu items when the actionMode was invalidated
    fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        if (mode == null || menu == null) return false
        updateMenuItems(menu)
        // should return true so that new menu items are populated
        return true
    }

    fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item!!.itemId) {
            MenuItemOption.Copy.id -> onCopyRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.Paste.id -> onPasteRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.Cut.id -> onCutRequested?.invoke()
            MenuItemOption.SelectAll.id -> onSelectAllRequested?.invoke()
            else -> return false
        }
        mode?.finish()
        return true
    }

    fun onDestroyActionMode() {
        onActionModeDestroy?.invoke()
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    internal fun updateMenuItems(menu: Menu) {
        addOrRemoveMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Copy, onCopyRequested)
        addOrRemoveMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Paste, onPasteRequested)
        addOrRemoveMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.Cut, onCutRequested)
        addOrRemoveMenuItem(menu, MenuItemOption.SelectAll, onSelectAllRequested)
    }

    internal fun addMenuItem(menu: Menu, item: MenuItemOption) {
        menu.add(0, item.id, item.order, item.titleResource)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
    }

    private fun addOrRemoveMenuItem(
        menu: Menu,
        item: MenuItemOption,
        callback: (() -> Unit)?
    ) {
        when {
            callback != null && menu.findItem(item.id) == null -> addMenuItem(menu, item)
            callback == null && menu.findItem(item.id) != null -> menu.removeItem(item.id)
        }
    }
}

internal enum class MenuItemOption(val id: Int) {
    Copy(0),
    Paste(1),
    Cut(2),
    SelectAll(3);

    val titleResource: Int
        get() = when (this) {
            Copy -> android.R.string.copy
            Paste -> android.R.string.paste
            Cut -> android.R.string.cut
            SelectAll -> android.R.string.selectAll
        }

    /**
     * This item will be shown before all items that have order greater than this value.
     */
    val order = id
}

@RequiresApi(23)
internal class FloatingTextActionModeCallback(
    private val callback: TextActionModeCallback
) : ActionMode.Callback2() {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return callback.onActionItemClicked(mode, item)
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return callback.onCreateActionMode(mode, menu)
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return callback.onPrepareActionMode(mode, menu)
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        callback.onDestroyActionMode()
    }

    override fun onGetContentRect(
        mode: ActionMode?,
        view: View?,
        outRect: android.graphics.Rect?
    ) {
        val rect = callback.rect
        outRect?.set(
            rect.left.toInt(),
            rect.top.toInt(),
            rect.right.toInt(),
            rect.bottom.toInt()
        )
    }
}

internal class PrimaryTextActionModeCallback(
    private val callback: TextActionModeCallback
) : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        return callback.onActionItemClicked(mode, item)
    }

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return callback.onCreateActionMode(mode, menu)
    }

    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return callback.onPrepareActionMode(mode, menu)
    }

    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
        callback.onDestroyActionMode()
    }
}

